# Display the categories chosen by the user

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and having trouble retrieving the data from my table. Here is my schema to better understand my problem:

[image]

In my **household_head** table I have the name of the household, the **residence** type of the household, **water_source** of household, **electricity_source** of the household table etc.

The **residence**, **water_source** and **electricity_source** etc. are categories from the **sdoh_category** table.

I want to display the selected categories in the table.blade.php, but I am so confused about how to query the data because I do not know how to display the specific **sdoh_categories** that belongs to a specific **sdoh**.

[image]

And also, display in the dropdown the specific **sdoh_categories** in which the **sdoh_category** belongs to the sdoh:

[image]

for example, in my first dropdown, I want to only show the residence categories such as owned and rent, in the second dropdown I want to only show the water_source categories, such as the faucet and well.

Answer (score 1):

You should build model relations correctly:

```
class Sdoh extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sdoh';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SdohCategory::class);
    }
}

class SdohCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sdoh_category';

    public function sdoh()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sdoh::class);
    }

    public function householdCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SdohCategoryHousehold::class);
    }
}

class SdohCategoryHousehold extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sdoh_category_household';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SdohCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function householdHead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(HouseholdHead::class, 'household_head_id');
    }
}

class HouseholdHead extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'household_head';

    public function categoryHouseholds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SdohCategoryHousehold::class, 'household_head_id');
    }
}
```

retrieve data:

```
$households = HouseholdHead::with('categoryHouseholds.category')->get();
$residenceCategories = Sdoh::where('sdoh', 'residence')->first()->categories;
$waterSourceCategories = Sdoh::where('sdoh', 'water_source')->first()->categories;
```

And in table.blade.php, you can loop through this data:

```
@foreach($households as $household)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $household->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $household->name }}</td>
        @foreach($household->categoryHouseholds as $categoryHousehold)
            <td>{{ $categoryHousehold->category->category }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach

//looping categories
<select name="residence">
    @foreach($residenceCategories as $residenceCategory)
        <option value="{{ $residenceCategory->id }}">{{ $residenceCategory->category }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select name="water_source">
    @foreach($waterSourceCategories as $waterSourceCategory)
        <option value="{{ $waterSourceCategory->id }}">{{ $waterSourceCategory->category }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: How about when I store the selected category from the dropdown to my database ?