# Store the selected category from the dropdown to my database

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and need help storing the category data from my dropdown to my database. Here is the schema to understand my problem.

[image]

I have successfully displayed the date from the database to my dropdown thanks to this : [Display the categories chosen by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77416074/display-the-categories-chosen-by-the-user). Now I want to store the selected values that was selected to the user to the corresponding tables.

I am so dumb with Query Builder atm, if you have good resources for me to learn QB as a beginner, then it is much appreciated.

This is the controller to redirect user to the add household :

```
public function create()
{
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $env_hazards = EnvHazard::all();
    $categories = SDOHCategory::all();


    $residenceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Residence')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $constructionCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'House Construction')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $waterSourceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Water Source')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $toiletCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Toilet Facility')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $electricityCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Electricity Source ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $incomeCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Combined Family Income')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $religionCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Religion ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $familyCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Family Type')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $incomeCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Combined Family Income ')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $garbageCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Garbage Disposal')->first()->sdoh_category;


    $dentalCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Dental Healthcare ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $preventiveCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Preventive Procedure')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $medicalCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Medical Services ')->first()->sdoh_category;

    $healthcaretCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Healthcare  ')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $exposureCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Exposure to Unhealthy Behavior')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $insuranceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Health Insurance ')->first()->sdoh_category;


    return view('household_create', compact('puroks', 'categories', 'env_hazards', 'residenceCategories', 'constructionCategories' ,'waterSourceCategories','toiletCategories', 'electricityCategories', 'incomeCategories', 'religionCategories', 'familyCategories'  ,'dentalCategories', 'preventiveCategories', 'medicalCategories', 'healthcaretCategories', 'exposureCategories', 'insuranceCategories', 'garbageCategories'));
}
```

I dont know what would be the code for the store method.

Answer (score 0):

You use ->first()->sdoh_category for what? you can use  ->first(); instead.

I think is better if you change your table to:

```
sdoh_category :
  - id
  - category

sdoh :
  - id
  - category_id
  - sdoh
```

For Store :

```
in blade :
<select name="sdoh_category">
  @foreach($sdohCategory as $data)
    <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->category }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>

in controller :
Public function store(Request $request)
{
  $sdoh = new SDOH;
  $sdoh->category_id = $request->sdoh_category;
  $sdoh->save();

  return redirect()->route('sdoh.index')->with('success', 'Success Message');
}
```